# how do I get the value of an environment variable in Applescript?

Tags: applescript

Specifically, I need to retrieve the value of the current user's HOME variable. But I would prefer that the answers be generically applicable to any environment variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`system attribute "HOME"` retrieves the value of environment variable `HOME`.

The mechanism works generically:

```applescript
set envVarName to "SHELL"    # sample variable name
system attribute envVarName  # returns, e.g., "/bin/bash"
```